# unexpected key error in Pandas multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, keyerror

The error appears only to occur when the column name is the integer value 0 (as opposed to the character '0').  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    1:[7,3,2,1,2],
    'Foo':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    '0':[2,4,6,8,10],
    '3':['1','2','3','4','5']
})

In [232]: df.set_index(['Foo', '0']).loc[('A',2)]
Out[232]: 
1    7
3    1
Name: (A, 2), dtype: object
```

In this case, the values for columns 1 and '3' are returned correctly, however the query returns a key error if I change the name of the third column from '0' to 0; even though the multi-index appears correct.

```
dg = pd.DataFrame({
    1:[7,3,2,1,2],
    'Foo':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    0:[2,4,6,8,10],
    '3':['1','2','3','4','5']
})

In[245]: dg.set_index(['Foo', 0])
Out[245]: 
        1  3
Foo 0       
A   2   7  1
    4   3  2
    6   2  3
B   8   1  4
    10  2  5

In[246]: dg.set_index(['Foo', 0]).loc[('A',2)]
Out[246]:  
Traceback (most recent call last):

. . . 
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type

KeyError: 'A'
```

No key error is raised when I use the columns 'Foo' and 1 to index the data frame:

```
df.set_index(['Foo', 1]).loc[('A',2)]
Out[237]: 
0    6
3    3
Name: (A, 2), dtype: object
```

Any insight would be helpful, as my use-case requires data-frames with integer column names.

I am using pandas version: 0.25.3
and Python version: 3.7.4

in an IPython environment (version 7.10.1, via anaconda/spyder)
on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately for me, this returns: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Comment: For more help on this, see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#integer-indexing.

Comment: You won't get the error if your column names are all strings. `dg.columns = dg.columns.astype(str)`, then `dg = dg.set_index(['Foo', '0'])`. You can then access the data via `dg.loc[('A', 2), :]`

Comment: Thanks; changing the column type fixed my issue; based on the documentation it seems like this behavior is by design and I'll have to adapt accordingly.  It still seems odd that non-zero integers do not have this issue.

Comment: Using integers as column names is discouraged, as data selection becomes ambiguous in certain cases. Try to use strings for column names when possible.

Comment: But this is almost certainly a bug where `pandas` gets confused by the `0` when it shouldn't. The DataFrame selection works without issue: `dg.loc[[('A', 2)]]`. I also wouldn't say that using integers as columns names is discouraged. `pandas` does create a RangeIndex by default with no headers, so it shouldn't struggle with them.

Comment: I'd report this as a bug. It's the column name being the integer 0 that is the problem. Changing `dg.set_index(['Foo', 1])` would work as expected